# index of finite subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a finite subgroup of a group $G$ (finite or infinite). Is the amount of left cosets (index) of $H$ in $G$ always finite ? I suspect this is true but I cannot seem to find a bijection between $H$ and the set of all cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: No.  Examples are not hard to manufacture, say, if you consider direct products.

Comment: Also, the rough idea of the proof of Lagrange should tell you this is false (in general).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The subgroup $H = \{\pm 1\}$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^*$ of non-zero reals has infinitely many cosets.  The cosets of $H$ are pairs of the form $\{-a, a\}$ for non-zero real $a$.  Certainly there can't be finitely many such pairs to exhaust all of $\mathbb{R}^*$.